# dijit dialog resize complexity

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

i am having dialog defined  like  below

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" id="DetailDialog" class="dijitDialog" ...
```

I just invoked grid inside the dialogwith 10 columns.

```js
var dlg = dijit.byId("DetailDialog");

dlg.set("content", this.Details);
dlg.show();

this._grid.refresh(); 
dlg.resize();

domStyle.set(dojo.byId('fDetailDialog'), {
    left: "162px"
});
```

The problem is, the dialog loaded with content center but the proper alignment happened only after scroll the page the size and width of the columns are proper.

May I know the best solution for alignment of dialog and resize, especially when we create dialog using div based approach.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description (in proper English). I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. There's one thing I already can say and that's that it's not recommended to change the position of the dialog using CSS and the DOM node of the widget.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling "layout" method and then resize. If we add elements inside dialog programmatically, call layout to avoid display issues with dialog.

```
var dialog = dijit.byId("dialogID");
...
dialog.layout();
dialog.resize();
```